# Function invocation every secoтd time?

Tags: javascript, closures

Recently I got test task at the project, it is fairly simple:

```
const _ = require('underscore');

// Challenge:
//
// Write a function that accepts as argument a "function of one variable", and returns a new
// function.  The returned function should invoke the original parameter function on every "odd"
// invocation, returning undefined on even invocations.
//
// Test case:
//  function to wrap via alternate(): doubleIt, which takes a number and returns twice the input.
//  input to returned function: 1,2,3,4,9,9,9,10,10,10
//  expected output: 2, undefined, 6, undefined, 18, undefined, 18, undefined, 20, undefined

const input = [1,2,3,4,9,9,9,10,10,10];
const doubleIt = x => x * 2;

const alternate = (fn) => {
  // Implement me!
  //
  // The returned function should only invoke fn on every
  // other invocation, returning undefined the other times.
}

var wrapped = alternate(doubleIt)

_.forEach(input, (x) => console.log(wrapped(x)))
// expected output: 2, undefined, 6, undefined, 18, undefined, 18, undefined, 20, undefined
```

And my solution was:

```
const alternate = (fn) => {
  let odd = false;

  return (x) => {
    odd = !odd;

    if (odd) {
      return fn(x);
    }

    return undefined;
  };
};

// An alternate solution if ternary operator (?) is allowed according to coding standards used on the project.
// Sometimes it's treated as bad practise.
const alternateShort = (fn) => {
  let odd = false;

  return (x) => (odd = !odd) ? fn(x) : undefined;
};
```

And I got the reply that tech lead didn't like my solution at all and I'm not hired to the project.
I'm really confused, do you have any idea what else he could expect?

Comment: Your code works fine. Only thing I'd change is the assignment inside the conditional (which is often confusing and forbidden by linters), but that's not *that* bad - it's opinion-based. I'd ask the code reviewer what he would've done differently, I don't see anything at all significant to change.

Comment: I *would* definitely change the first snippet, if that's the test case code - importing a big library just to iterate over an array is extremely silly, but that sounds like something not in your control.

Comment: You're actually asking for code review which is off-topic here. But you may ask it at [related site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Off-topic, but if it were me, if an interviewer rejected my code that looked like your solution without any explanation, I'd take that as a sign that I very likely wouldn't want to work at that company anyway.

Comment: `?` is not a ternary operator, it's a [*punctuator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-punctuators). `? :` together are the [*conditional operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-conditional-operator), the only ternary operator in ECMAScript. ;-)